# Sql order by two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 relations: tables and tablegroups. One table can be in one tablegroup and one tablegroup contains multiple tables.

I need a select that returns the following output:

All tables from the tablegroup with the sortid 0 -> the tables again sorted by their sortid

and so on for all the tables.

Is this possible in Sql(Mysql dbms)?

Table

```
table_id, name, pax, createdate, lastupdate, tablegroup_id, sort_id, 

'2', 'tisch 02', '6', NULL, NULL, '1', '3' 
'3', 'tisch 03', '4', NULL, NULL, '1', '1'
'4', 'tisch 04', '2', NULL, NULL, '1', '2'
'5', 'tisch 05', '8', NULL, NULL, '1', '4'
'6', 'tisch 101', '4', NULL, NULL, '2', '1'
'7', 'tisch 102', '6', NULL, NULL, '2', '2'
'8', 'stube 01', '2', NULL, NULL, '3', '2' 
'9', 'stube 02', '3', NULL, NULL, '3', '1'
```

Tablegroups

```
tablegroup_id, name, notiz, color, customer_id, sort_id, visible
'1', 'garten', NULL, '1', '1', '2', '1'
'2', 'lounge', NULL, '2', '1', '3', '1'
'3', 'stube', '', '7', '1', '1', '1'
```

Expected Output:

```
'stube 01' 
'stube 02' 
'tisch 03'
'tisch 04'
'tisch 05'
'tisch 101'
'tisch 102'
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output will really help.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you want:
You want all the items (records) from `table` sorted first in order of the associated `tablegroup` sort id, and then second by the `table` sort id?

Comment: Don't you have a way to explain it better? I think what you want is easy but the way yo use to express it is very confusing

Comment: yes, i know the explanation is very confusing, but somehow sticky bit managed to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner join `table` and `tablegroups` on a common `tablegroup_id` and `ORDER BY` the `sort_id` of `tablegroups` and then the `sort_id` of `table`.

```
SELECT t.name
       FROM table t
            INNER JOIN tablegroups tg
                       ON tg.tablegroup_id = t.tablegroup_id
       ORDER BY tg.sort_id,
                t.sort_id;
```

Comment: not gives the desired result `SELECT t.name
       FROM table t
       ORDER BY t.name;` is closer to the result even if logic depends on only one table. i.e. question is not clear enough.